# Non-local heat transport

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Heat transport at the nanoscale is said to be affected by non-local effects that do not appear at the macroscale. A popular extension of the Fourier law that accounts for this effects  is the Guyer-Krumhansl equation,
\begin{equation}
\tau\dot{\mathbf{q}}+\mathbf{q}=-k\nabla T+\ell^2(\nabla^2\mathbf{q}+2\nabla\nabla\cdot\mathbf{q}),
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ and $\ell$ are non-classical parameters which are called thermal relaxation time and phonon mean free path. The second derivatives of the heat flux are said to account for the non-local effects. However, I cannot find any explanation for why these effects are included by including these terms into the Fourier law.

Can anyone help me to understand the interprete these terms?

Comment: Which terms? $\tau$ and $\ell$? Or the second derivatives of the heat flux?

Comment: I want to understand the second derivatives of the heat flux. Is there a physical interpretation, for example? Sorry if I haven't been clear enough.